# Add two indexes in char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I have a char* array and I want to add each two consecutive indexes and store it in another array. For example the functionality should be something like this

```
  char* wordsArray="The quick brown fox.";
  char* array; 
  array=new char[size-1];       \\assume size is a declared variable 
  for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)   
       array[i]=wordsArray[i]+wordsArray[i+1];
```

Now, array would have "The quick" on the first index, "quick brown" on the second and and "brown fox" on the third.
What is the proper way to do such a thing?

Edit: Suppose we can not use the built-in STL classes and algorithms (vector, etc)

Comment: Take into account that indexed access to an array of characters access individual characters, not words. If your logical unit is a word and not character you have to find the words first (there are many methods for that), or work with words to start with. `std::vector<std::string> sentence = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox"};`

Comment: Minor note: As of C++11 `char* wordsArray="The quick brown fox.";` is illegal. string literals, such as `"The quick brown fox."`, are constant arrays of characters. You cannot assign a constant value to a non-constant pointer to prevent mistakes where someone tries to write to the pointed at, and potentially unchangable, value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::vector` and `std::string` to do this easily.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<std::string> wordsArray = {"The", "quick", "brown", "fox."};
    std::vector<std::string> array;
    int size = wordsArray.size();

    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)   
       array.push_back(wordsArray[i]+ " " + wordsArray[i+1]);

    for(int i=0; i<size-1; i++)   
       std::cout << array[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
The quick
quick brown
brown fox.
```